# Populate data in datatable from MySQL: Php Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I'm trying to retrieve the data from MySQL database and push it into datatable, but the data table is not being populated with the data.

I'm able to get the data in the backend when I console log it, but I'm not being able to push it into datatable.

Any help will be appriciated

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <style>
        tfoot {
            display: table-header-group;
        }
    </style>
    <body>

        <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">control_id</th>
                    <th scope="col">sample_id</th>
                    <th scope="col">sample_nm</th>
                    <th scope="col">sample_type_nm</th>
                    <th scope="col">sample_type_with_nm</th>
                    <th scope="col">variant_type</th>
                    <th scope="col">output_location</th>
                    <th scope="col">object_type</th>
                    <th scope="col">output_type</th>
                    <th scope="col">oncotree_nm</th>
                    <th scope="col">status</th>
                    <th scope="col">pipeline_status</th>
                    <th scope="col">oncsuite_status</th>
                    <th scope="col">control_completion_status</th>
                    <th scope="col">send_oncsuite_status</th>
                    <th scope="col">api_log_creation_dt</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>control_id</th>
                <th>sample_id</th>
                <th>sample_nm</th>
                <th>sample_type_nm</th>
                <th>sample_type_with_nm</th>
                <th>variant_type</th>
                <th>output_location</th>
                <th>object_type</th>
                <th>output_type</th>
                <th>oncotree_nm</th>
                <th>status</th>
                <th>pipeline_status</th>
                <th>oncsuite_status</th>
                <th>control_completion_status</th>
                <th>send_oncsuite_status</th>
                <th>api_log_creation_dt</th>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').DataTable( {
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "../model/getData.php",
                        "type": "POST"
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        {data: 'control_id'},
                        {data: 'sample_id'},
                        {data: 'sample_nm'},
                        {data: 'sample_type_nm'},
                        {data: 'sample_type_with_nm'},
                        {data: 'variant_type'},
                        {data: 'output_location'},
                        {data: 'object_type'},
                        {data: 'output_type'},
                        {data: 'oncotree_nm'},
                        {data: 'status'},
                        {data: 'pipeline_status'},
                        {data: 'oncsuite_status'},
                        {data: 'ontrol_completion_status'},
                        {data: 'send_oncsuite_status'},
                        {data: 'api_log_creation_dt'}
                    ]
                } );

            } );
                
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

getData.php

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

class getData
{
    public function selectData()
    {
        $output = array();
        $pdo = Db::getInstance();
        $query = "SELECT control_id, sample_id, sample_nm, sample_type_nm, sample_type_with_nm, variant_type, output_location, object_type, output_type, oncotree_nm, status, pipeline_status, oncsuite_status, control_completion_status, send_oncsuite_status, api_log_creation_dt FROM vonc_wes.view_control_variant_context_new";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        try {
            $stmt->execute();
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e;
        }
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach ($rows as $row) {

            $subarray = array();
            $subarray["control_id"] = $row[0];
            $subarray["sample_id"] = $row[1];
            $subarray["sample_nm"] = $row[2];
            $subarray["sample_type_nm"] = $row[3];
            $subarray["sample_type_with_nm"] = $row[4];
            $subarray["variant_type"] = $row[5];
            $subarray["output_location"] = $row[6];
            $subarray["object_type"] = $row[7];
            $subarray["output_type"] = $row[8];
            $subarray["oncotree_nm"] = $row[9];
            $subarray["status"] = $row[10];
            $subarray["pipeline_status"] = $row[11];
            $subarray["oncsuite_status"] = $row[12];
            $subarray["ontrol_completion_status"] = $row[13];
            $subarray["send_oncsuite_status"] = $row[14];
            $subarray["api_log_creation_dt"] = $row[15];
            array_push($output, $subarray);
        }
        $outputJson = json_encode($output);
        echo $outputJson;
    }
}

$getallData             = new getData();
$getallData->selectData();
```

The output from getData.php is

```
[{"control_id":"1","sample_id":"8043","sample_nm":"ST","sample_type_nm":"NORMAL","sample_type_with_nm":":NORMAL","variant_type":"gatk4","output_location":"atic.tsv","object_type":"tsv","output_type":"gatk4","oncotree_nm":"NORMA","status":"2","pipeline_status":"2","oncsuite_status":"0","ontrol_completion_status":"0","send_oncsuite_status":"400","api_log_creation_dt":"2020-04-1"},{"control_id":"12","sample_id":"843","sample_nm":"ST","sample_type_nm":"NORMAL","sample_type_with_nm":":NORMAL","variant_type":"gatk4","output_location":"atic.tsv","object_type":"tsv","output_type":"gatk4","oncotree_nm":"NORMA","status":"2","pipeline_status":"2","oncsuite_status":"0","ontrol_completion_status":"0","send_oncsuite_status":"400","api_log_creation_dt":"2020-04-1"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the DataTables documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax):

> Note that DataTables expects the table data to be an array of items in the `data` parameter of the object (use the `ajax.dataSrc` option of ajax as an object, if your data is formatted differently)

The object you're sending back is just an array, not an object with a `data` property.  The simplest approach would probably be to make use of [that `ajax.dataSrc` option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) and set it to an empty string:

```
"ajax": {
  "url": "../model/getData.php",
  "type": "POST",
  "dataSrc": ""
}
```

Alternatively you'd want to modify your PHP code to create an object with a `data` property and set your `$output` as the value of that property, then `json_encode` and output that object.