# Datatables Ajax how to append data to existing table data

Tags: ajax, datatable

> **Using Datatables Version 1.11.50**

## The Source Data:

We have an SQL dataset retrieved from around 10-12 different [joined] tables, featuring in total over 11,000 rows and between 40-45 columns of information. This amounts to over 500,000 units of information.

The SQL we have for this is, very large, but it works well and on the MySQL console this executes **retrieving the data in around 6 seconds**.

However, the data needs to be presented in an HTML Javascript Datatable and we've been previously using the method of "building" the data page in the HTML, so that when the page loads, the `<table>` element is populated with ~11,670 rows of `<tr><td>...</td></tr>` before outputting to browser and being processed by the Datatables script.

## Beginning working with Ajax:

This is obviously very slow and page loads were around 190 seconds. So I've moved across to using AJAX to call the data post HTML load; but this presents other issues I can't resolve.

Current Example setup below:

## Example Layout

Example Datatables AJAX reference (separate JS file):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let uniShow = true;
    var t = $('#outputList').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "test_ajax.php",
            "type": "POST",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        stateSave: true,
        deferRender: true,
        ...
        ... etc. etc.
        ...
      });
});
```

Example AJAX PHP file

```
<?php

$sqlResult = SQL array of arrays of SQL tables data .

/***
 * $sqlResult is the full array of data returned by MySQL
 * Typically 11k rows
 ***/

foreach ($sqlResult as $row){
    $output[$loopCounter][] = ""; // counter column.
    $output[$loopCounter][] = "<span class='cellValueHider'>".$row['see_id']."</span><a href='/link/". $row['id']."'>". $name."</a>".$campFlag
        .$closedFlag.$deletedFlag;

    $output[$loopCounter][] = trim($row['town'],' ,');
    $output[$loopCounter][] = $row['postcode'];
    $output[$loopCounter][] = $row['county'];

   .... etc. etc....

    }

$result = json_enode($output);

print $result;
?>
```

Example HTML file table:

```
<body>
<table id="outputList">
        <thead><tr>
            <th data-count='1' data-priority="1"><!-- auto generated row counter--></th>
            <th data-count='2' class='dt-head-center' data-priority="1">Name</th>
            <th data-count='3' class='dt-head-center' data-priority="5">Town</th>
            <th data-count='4' class='dt-head-center' data-priority="2">Postcode</th>
            <th data-count='5' class='dt-head-center' data-priority="5">County</th>
            <th data-count='6' class='dt-head-center' data-priority="5">Region</th>
            <th data-count='7' class='dt-head-center' data-priority="5">Country</th>
            
            ... etc, etc.... 

            <th data-count='44' class='dt-head-center' data-priority="2">Status<BR>(2020)</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <!-- ajax populated here -->
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
```

## The Slowdown

The above system does work,but the AJAX result is a single call lump rather than trying to get the AJAX to call in chunks of say, 200 rows at a time. This makes the Ajax no faster than loading the data upon the table page HTML load (which takes around 190 seconds).

### QUESTION

How can I get the Datatables AJAX to call the first 200 rows, then populate them, while cycling back to the AJAX to call the next, next, next, until all 11k rows are retrieved?

I just can't see how to append AJAX data and can't find any sort of example of this on the Datatables documentation.

[This is a similar question (up to this point)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64916477/populate-data-in-datatable-from-mysql-php-ajax).

I have also read [this Question about using AJAX to load large data sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600150/jquery-datatables-load-large-data).

## Issue

The part I don't seem to understand, is how to tell Datatables to "chunk" the Ajax data? Examples from the Official Documentation and the above linked questions presents the AJAX as a single call-retrieve loop rather than than a cycle of calling until the dataset is exhausted.

I want to call the first 2/4/500 records on the pageload, these get processed and put into the table and the output shown to the user, and *then* this 500-row call and retrieval happening in the background until all is loaded (22-23 loops).

## Related:

How can I get the Ajax to outout the JSON data before the whole block of data has completed loading?

Alternatively, how to cycle the AJAX script loading without cycling *infinitum* ?

This would present a much faster load to the user. The first load of the page would be direct from the data -- ie the page won't need to sort the data it gets from the SQL, it's already in the default order (sorting may occur with users ordering the data by column but this would hopefully occur post-data collection).

### UPDATE:

`Serverside` AJAX looks like it's quite heavy on the server and involves a lot more communication. There is a secondary issue that once the data is in front of the user they will be ordering/reordering it by both primary and secondary sorting columns and overall it feels like the data sorting should be on the browser side rather than persistent retrieval calls to the AJAX server side script.

So, I can use some SESSION data and counters to populate the server side script and output additional rows to the Datatables, but I can't find any questions on here or any documentation on the Datatables Docs about how to go about this.

Concept:

HTML page load
DataTables Load
AJAX call 1 - populate first X rows
Browser/page/Table is usable to the user.
AJAX call 2,3,4,.... - repeated AJAX calls until 100% of table data is retrieved into the browser.

For example; we have 11,600 rows of 45 columns of data. The first AJAX calls 300 rows and outputs, then [immediate] later AJAX calls will load the next 500, etc. etc. until all 11,600 rows are sitting in the datatable.

### How can I append later AJAX calls to an existing datatable?

Comment: I think you need to switch on the [serverSide option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide) and then read the [Server-Side processing page](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side). So "AJAX" only means "retrieve the data from the server", while processing still takes place on the client, whereas "server-side" means that the processing, including paging is done on the server.

Comment: AFAIK, "chunked" loading is only available with the `serverSide` option, and pagination applied - then the AJAX endpoint will get pagination parameters passed as well, and can return the right chunk for the current page. https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide

Comment: By the way: I find a processing time of 6 seconds completely unacceptable for a web-interface. You might find that, even with server-side processing, or dare I say: _"Especially with server-side processing"_, response times may be way to long, simply because you notice it a lot more. Try to get response times under 200 ms if you can. This should be possible with a proper database design and the low number of rows you need to retrieve.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the result is on a shared server and there's a lot of calculations and stuff being done within the SQL query; it's a big and complex query and while 5-6 seconds may be slow for that, it's a hell of a lot better than the 190 seconds it takes to output the result to the Datatables. I realise working on this will not get table data populated that fast, but must be quicker than 3 minutes it is currently.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware my fear with doing the datatables calls server side is that the manual appears to state that all table manipulation has to be parsed via the server, which will add significant overhead as the users will want to primary- and secondarily- order by different columns. If there's a way of appending data to the Ajax and simply requesting so all the ordering work is done browser side that feels like it would be best overall

Comment: @CBroe ^^ FYI if you have thoughts on this

Comment: If you choose for server-side processing, all processing, including ordering, has to be done server side. You may need to redesign the query you're running. Perhaps split it up in more manageable parts, partition long tables, or do some of the processing in-memory using SQLite. There are many...many ways to improve the performance of queries.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the current bottleneck is not the SQL but the size of the data, this is exactly the sort of issue I think AJAX can make better but I can't see how to do this with Datatables. Please see my updated question. Thank you. :)

Comment: Size should not be a problem, ever. The problem here is the complexity of your query. Since I don't know what your query, or output, looks like, there's not much more I can say. Very often not all the tables are needed in the first query you do server-side. Addition information, and processing, of the data in the rows that the first query retrieved, can be added in later. Also consider: Not all columns need to be sortable/searchable.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I think we may be misunderstanding each other; the mySQL runs with full results in just under 6 seconds. The PHP / Datatables JS outputs these same results in an HTML table in 190 seconds. While I'm sure the mySQL can be improved and streamlined, currently the aim is to reduce this 180 second issue which (according to browser diagnostics) is entirely down to Datatables only processing completed data, rather than acting asynchronously. Thanks.

Comment: Well, yes, server-side processing should be able to get the processing time down a lot from 180 seconds. Just give it a try. But if your AJAX calls still take seconds to process it won't be nice. Then you need to redesign your query/database. But you'll have to get there on your own. I'm just thinking ahead a bit.

Comment: @Martin  Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide ServerSide performance enhancing suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck what has this got to do with JQuery / Datatables output?

Comment: When you are trying to retrieve significant volumes of data, workload tuning becomes real important if you would like to REDUCE WAIT time for every query.

Comment: @WilsonHauck as outlined, the SQL data retrieval takes a few seconds, but the JS / Datatables processing takes Minutes .

Comment: There are a few comments suggesting other ways of accomplishing your task.  When server WAIT TIME becomes significant, get in touch.  View profile.

Comment: Depend on server-side for your processing needs and avoid JS / Datatables use entirely, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck datatables is a non-negotiable requirement.

Comment: Good luck.  When you would like to improve speed of your hosting server, please get in touch. Happy Thanksgiving.